# How to get the progress you are in React?

Tags: reactjs

For my school I need to develop an application where you can learn React. Before I can create this website I need to learn React itself. The question I was wondering is: "When do you know React". My teacher said, before you start developing the website you need to wonder yourself when do you know it? I need to find a way to make it measurable.

Also some tips by learning React or developing my website are welcome :)

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: I want to make the progress where I am in react measurable

Comment: This is quite a board question and probably not great for stack overflow. Anything you can learn which isn't trivial is almost impossible to know completely; I imagine your teacher means to suggest that you must draw an arbitrary line at some point and say that is the level to which you will teach. I think that certainly the best starting point for you is to learn at least some react, as if you don't know the library, it's almost impossible for you to have any idea about how to go about delineating it into teachable chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately stackoverflow community is not very helpful and nice when it comes to beginners, when they do not ask questions in the form this stackoverflow mob is expecting. I'm sorry you got a lot of down-votes for that question.

To give you a simple answer: Just start trying. Go to React's homepage and do the getting started tutorials.

Stackoverflow is best when you come here with a question what exactly you are trying to accomplish and **what you already tried**. So come back here if something you tried did not work, post the code you used and explain what you expect from the code is doing and explain what it is doing instead.

A side note: Do not listen to teachers who say something like that. That is impossible to measure. Also there are a lot of ways how to accomplish things in react. there are millions of libraries out there, React itself is changing quite a lot. For example now we are getting hooks and that will change everything.

Another suggestion that is the opposite of what your teacher told you: **start before** knowing react with your website. How even can he tell such a thing. Where or How should you learn React (or JavaScript or anything else) if you do not work on something real. Should you just learn it theoretically? No! That's a typical teacher thing. Forget it, go out, get your hands dirty, try to solve the real problems you have, and come back here if you need help.

Comment: I second that completely.
Start by taking an online course (udemy is great) and than start coding!

Make your project as good as you can. When it's finished, you'll have learned enough to find your weaknesses. And then: start again... from scratch!

Being a good developer is all about your willingness to refactor, restart, rebuild.